# Verifying properties of tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

I'm working with tensor products over modules using the following definition:

"Let $R$ be a ring and let $A_R,_RB$ be modules. Let $F$ denote the free abelian group on $A \times B$ and let $K$ denote the subgroup of $F$ that is generated by the elements $e_{(a'+a'',b)},-e_{(a',b)}-e_{(a'',b)}, e_{(a,b'+b'')}-e_{(a,b')}-e_{(a,b'')},e_{(ar,b)}-e_{(a,rb)}$, where $a,a',a'' \in A, b,b',b'' \in B, r \in R$. The quotient group $F/K$ is called the tensor product of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A \otimes_R B$. For every $(a,b) \in A \times B$, the coset $e_{(a,b)}+K$ is denoted $a \otimes b$."

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

"If $R$ is a ring, and $A_R, _RB$ are modules with $r \in R$, $a,a',a'' \in A$, $b,b'b,'' \in B$, then show that the following are true:
(1) $(a' + a'') \otimes b = (a' \otimes b) + (a'' \otimes b)$;
(2) $a \otimes (b'+b'')=(a \otimes b')+(a \otimes b'')$;
(3) $ar \otimes b=a \otimes rb$;
(4) $0_A \otimes b = a \otimes 0_B = 0_A \otimes 0_B = 0_{A \otimes_R B}$."

Am I able to prove this without using the basis elements? I have a proof using the basis elements and cosets, but I'm not sure if I should be doing that.

Comment: You of course mean the tensor product over R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example (1) really says
$$e_{(a'+a'',b)}+K=e_{a',b}+e_{a'',b}+K$$
(by definition, $a'\otimes b$ **is** the coset $e_{a',b}+K$ etc.)
or equivalently
$$e_{(a'+a'',b)}-(e_{a',b}+e_{a'',b})\in K.$$
This, of course, is part of the definition of $K$.

The same goes for (2) and (3). We see that the definition of $K$ is set up to make
all these work. As for (4), that needs some basic algebra:
$$0_A\otimes b=(0_A+0_A)\otimes b=(0_A\otimes b)+(0_A\otimes b)$$
using (1). This means that $0_A\otimes b$ must be  the zero element of $A\otimes B$.

Comment: Can you only prove this using the basis elements?

Comment: These "basis elements" were how you defined the tensor product. Unless you use an alternative definition of tensor product, it is inevitable that you use these basis elements.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much! :)